# Removing repetitive items from an array

Tags: android, arrays, repeat

I have a method for sorting and removing repetitive items from an array:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> sortArray(ArrayList<Integer> listForSort) {

    List<Integer> sortTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Sortedlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int[] array = new int[20];

for (int i = 0; i < listForSort.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = listForSort.get(i);
}

Arrays.sort(array);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!(Arrays.asList(sortTemp).contains((Integer)array[i])) && (array[i] != 0))   {
        Integer tempo = (Integer)array[i];
        Sortedlist.add(tempo);
        sortTemp.add(tempo);
        }
}
    return Sortedlist;
}
```

But my method doesn't remove the repeated items. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a Set. A Set does not allow a duplicate to be entered so you wont have to worry about removing them. Maybe like a SortedSet so the sorting and duplicate removal is automatic. ConcurrentSkipListSet, NavigableSet, TreeSet are all also SortedSet's.

Comment: thank you man! i did it according to your hint: HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(listForSort);
listForSort.clear();
listForSort.addAll(hs);

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile at all (`SortedList` that you try to return does not even exist within the context)?. 
Anyways, you should probably first create a dictionary (a.k.a. map/hash) for removing repetitions and then sort all the keys of this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this much harder on yourself. Both ArrayList and List implement the Comparable interface. Allowing you to call the compareTo method on any of their elements.

```
listForSort.get(i).compareTo(sortedList.get(i));
```

Take into account "falling off" the end of the list using List.hasNext() with Iterators. It will make your array operations much more effient.